# In Video file select audio track in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

a video file has multiple audio tracks so how I can select any one audio track in the flutter video_player package?

Answer (score 1):

Since `video_player` is a bareback package for which you need to implement every functionality yourself. I will suggest you to go with [BetterPlayer](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player), this provides lot of features without much work.

Your requirement of **Audio Track Selection** will be fulfilled by this without much work.

Comment: if answers helps you, please accept the answer.

Comment: how to implement video_player functionality?

Comment: @PriyankaRawat It seems that better_player implements audio track selection only for online video streams. It has method BetterPlayerController.setAudioTrack, but this method has a comment "Works only for HLS or DASH streams." Any idea about offline videos?